# Why does my app crash with NSInvalidArgumentException while trying to use dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970?

Tags: objective-c, ios, date, nsdate

I'm trying to create an NSDate with dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 but I keep getting an NSInvalidArgumentException. I can't figure out what's wrong with my syntax:

```
// [mutableItem valueForKey:@"date"] is a string which represents an integer of milliseconds

NSDate *dateObject = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:([[mutableItem valueForKey:@"date"] longLongValue]/1000)];
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check your mutableItem value?

Here's my working example:

```
NSString *mutableItem = @"1344981600000";

NSDate *dateObject = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:([mutableItem longLongValue]/1000)];

//dateObject = 2012-08-14 22:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: mutableItem is an NSMutableDictionary...it has a key called 'date' with a value thats a string (timestamp integer such as "1344981600000"). That's why I'm using [mutableItem valueForKey:@"date"]

Comment: Yes but he is asking you to check this : NSLog(@"%@",[mutableItem valueForKey:@"date"]);

Comment: NSLog(@"should be seconds string: %@", [mutableItem valueForKey:@"date"]); outputs should be seconds string: 1344984081

Answer (score 1):

If you divide by 1000 you divide it with an integer. If you divide by 1000. (DOT) then it might work.

dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: requires an NSTimeInterval which is a double.

Comment: I'm getting the same crash with the dot. I'm not sure I understand...I shouldn't convert to a longlong value, but instead a double? Should I be assigning the timestamp string to a NSTimeInterval beforehand? Could you give an example?

Comment: Sometimes if you divide a double or float by an integer you get an integer. And that can completely mess up with the code. It depends how the dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 is written.